# Cannot add rows to a table in LINQ to EntityFramework - AddObject and InsertOnSubmit BOTH missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-entities

I know it's supposed to be one or the other depending on whether using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities but any ideas why neither option (AddObject or InsertOnSubmit) is available to me? I am using LINQ to Entities so shouldn't I expect to see AddObject?

UPDATE: Per request, I am adding code.

Controller:

```
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Linq;

 ...Unimportant code...

 private DataModel db = new DataModel(); // <-- DataModel.edmx

 ...Unimportant code...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessApplication (HttpPostedFileBase file) {

        JobBoardUsersModel jm = new JobBoardUsersModel();

        ...jm properties are set...

        db.JobBoardUsers.Add(jm) // <- Here is where I cannot use AddObject or Add

        client.Send(message);

        jobDetails.IsApplied = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", jobDetails);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class JobSummaryModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddObject()` is a method on `ObjectSet<T>`, which is accessible on `ObjectContext`.But if you're using Entity Framework 4.1 or newer, you're likely working with a `DbContext`, which is a facade over the more complicated `ObjectContext` API.

The equivalent of `AddObject()` on `DbSet<T>` (which is what you're working with in a `DbContext`) is `Add()`.

See: [Add Entity using DBContext](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx)

You can also access the `ObjectContext` if you ever need to access anything that is not available on the `DbContext`...

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
```

As for `InsertOnSubmit()`, that is only available in Linq to SQL.

--- Update ---

```
JobBoardUsersModel jm = new JobBoardUsersModel();
```

should be...

```
JobBoardUser jm = new JobBoardUser();
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this is a little above my current level. I tried the "Add" method with my model as the argument and got an "invalid arguments" error.

Comment: No worries. You'll need to post more code and details to get more help on this.

Comment: I added some details. Hopefully this clarifies my problem.

Comment: What's the full invalid arguments error? It sounds like the wrong model is being added to the JobBoardUsers.

Comment: "The best overloaded method match for "System.Data.Entity.Dbset<JobBoard.Models.JobBoardUser>.Add(JobBoard.Models.JobBoardUser)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: OK that makes sense now... `JobBoardUsersModel jm = new JobBoardUsersModel();` should be `JobBoardUser jm = new JobBoardUser();`